# How to make the error bars move with the barplot when re-ordering factors?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am plotting a barplot with error bars. And here's what I got so far. The problem is that the error bars do not appear in the place where they should be. If I don't force the ID levels, by removing the `df2ID <- factor(df2$ID, level = c('Gary','Jack', 'Alice'))` line, everything looks fine.

```
ID = c(rep('Gary',10), rep('Jack',10), rep('Alice',10))
#Gary has lowest mean and sd, Alice has highest mean and sd
var1 = c(rnorm(1:10)*1+10,rnorm(1:10)*10+20, rnorm(1:10)*100+30)  
df <-data.frame(ID = ID, var1 = var1)
df2 <- ddply(df, 'ID', summarise, mean = mean(var1), sd = sd(var1))
df2$ID <- factor(df2$ID, level = c('Gary','Jack', 'Alice'))
limits <- aes(ymax = df2$mean + df2$sd, ymin = df2$mean - df2$sd)
ggplot(df2, aes(y=mean, x=ID))+geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  geom_errorbar(limits)+
  facet_grid(.~ID)
```

But I do need to keep that line so I can re-order the sequence of the panels. How can I make the error bars re-ordered too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never use `data.frame$column` with ggplot, it forces a full vector on to ggplot, bypassing the `data` argument which can know about groupings and such. In some basic plots it doesn't matter, but if you facet it's almost always a big problem.

So, to solve your problem, don't try to specify `limits` before the plot. Just delete that line and put the same code (without `df$`) in your `geom_errorbar`:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(y = mean, x = ID))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = mean + sd, ymin = mean - sd)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ ID)
```

If you are using facets and don't want every ID listed on each panel and on each x-axis, you can set, say `x = "a"` in the original `aes()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for the addition `x='a'` suggestion!